# I'm using Windows, and I want to use Dropbox to back up a folder outside my Dropbox directory

Tags: windows-xp, dropbox

On Mac OS X, I create a symbolic link to the folder I'm trying to back up, and put it in the Dropbox folder  (e.g. /Users/zachary/Dropbox/DocumentsBackup ---> /Users/zachary/Documents) and that solves my problem.

No idea how to do it on Windows XP, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of a symbolic link on Windows is the [junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point). You can create junctions with the appropriately-named utility [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) from Mark Russinovich at Microsoft.

```
junction.exe C:\Users\Zachary\Dropbox\Documents C:\Users\Zachary\Documents
```

On Windows Vista and later, there also exists the command line utility [`mklink`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx).