# Can you link an NTFS junction point to a directory on a Network Attached Storage?

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs, dropbox, junction

[I'm using Windows, and I want to use Dropbox to back up a folder outside my Dropbox directory](https://superuser.com/questions/337982/im-using-windows-and-i-want-to-use-dropbox-to-back-up-a-folder-outside-my-dropb/337986#337986).  So I want to create a junction point from my target directory to my Dropbox folder.  According to the [NTFS Junction Point article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) on Wikipedia, also linked from the Dropbox answer:

> Junction points can only link to directories on a local volume; junction points to remote shares are unsupported.

I am looking to link to a directory on networked attached storage, which would not be a local volume, I believe.  What should I do?

Comment: Adding it as a drive letter is not an option?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link).

Comment: I think Symbolic Links only work on Vista+, and I think the target system also needs to support them.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice he had specified the OS in the tag.  AFAIK, there is no possible solution on Windows XP.

Comment: Also, symbolic links casn't be made to network drives, even if they have a local drive letter.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food, that seems to contradict Wikipedia which states `a symbolic link can also point to a file or remote SMB network path`.

Comment: @Zoredache, I gave it another go.  I can't create a Junction to a network path.  I can create a Symbolic Link to a network path or mapped drive, but I can only navigate it in Explorer.  I can't use `cd` or `dir` on the link.  It may work for Dropbox, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food: The reason you can't use `cd` or `dir` on a networked drive is because a symlink contain, literally, a path to its target.  Since the `cmd` interpreter cannot handle UNC paths, it will fail.  Try `pushd \\UNCpath`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to fake it with a combination of symbolic links and networking mapping with the `subst` and `mklink` tools, though obviously `mklink` is unavailable on Windows XP. This will work for user navigation purposes, but if software explicitly blocks network paths and checks for maps directing to them, it probably will detect this workaround and fail to traverse the directory in question.

```
subst M: \\COMPUTERNAME\SHARENAME
mklink /D C:\Users\John\Dropbox\MyFakeFolder\ M:\
```

Since the symbolic link itself does not contain a UNC path, you will be able to navigate to this folder in the command line without any problems, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using a  UNC path you can do like this:

1. Using CMD open the location where you want to create the LINK
2. Run the command

   ```
   mklink /D <Target or Link Name> \\UNC Path
   ```