# Change drive calling an executable

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a .exe file that receives a script as parameter. This .exe looks for the file in a specific path decided by the creator, for example C:\scripts

If the script is in another directory (C:\MyDir) a way of calling the exe is the following:

```
myExe .\..\..\MyDir\myScript.py
```

If the script is in another drive I have a problem because something like

```
myExe .\..\..\Y:\MyDir\myScript.py
```

doesn't work. How can I change the directory at the time of calling the exe?

Comment: try putting the full path to the script between quotes

Comment: that doesn't work i get this error:
invalid file name: C:\\Mercury\\SitePackages\\Y:\\myDir\myScript.py
being C:\\Mercury\\SitePackages\\ the hardcoded path

Comment: Use softlinks or junctions https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_links

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/338719/can-you-link-an-ntfs-junction-point-to-a-directory-on-a-network-attached-storage#comment370072_338747

Answer (score 2):

`..\..Y:\MyDir\myScript.py` is not a valid path in Windows.  This is a an attempt at a relative path and relative paths cannot jump across drives.

If `myExe Y:\MyDir\myScript.py` doesn't work then it seems the author of the .exe has hardcoded C: into the file.  If this is the case then it might work if you create a shortcut to your script on your C: drive and then pass the .exe the path to the shortcut.

Update after your comment:

Since Y: is a mapped drive you can also try using the full UNC path to the file.  If Y: is mapped to `\\somesvr\someshare` then try

`myExe \\somesvr\someshare\MyDir\myScript.py`

You can see the UNC path to the share in Windows Explorer under Computer.

Comment: The issue is that Y is a net drive that all my colleagues has access and i want to centralized everything there so everyone can call the .exe using the same .cmd. if a move Y:\MyDir\myScript.py to C: then it works but is not what i would like to do

Comment: See my update about using the UNC path

Comment: i tried that but then \\somesvr\someshare is joined to the hardcoded path and the exe doesn't find the file

Comment: Ok, then you might have to try using the shortcut.  If a shortcut doesn't work, afraid you might be out of luck unless you can contact the author of the .exe